# Service timed out: Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I always get the exception: "Exception: Service timed out: Spreadsheets" Why does this happen and would it help to try the method updateSpec(spec)? It always happens when I got to this specific line:

```
let turnamentGames = response("https://europe.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/by-puuid/" + puuid + "/ids?type=tourney&start=0&count=100&startTime=" + (parseInt((currentTime / 1000) - 15552000)) + "&" + apikey.substring(1));
```

It also takes a long time (30s) to run the first output of the initial methods first line:

```
function main() {
  console.info("MAIN: STARTED");
  currentTime = new Date();
  if (currentTime.getHours() > 11) analyse();
  else console.warn("MAIN: Next search at 12:00");
}
```

This should not be that complicated. Is it then just a issue of bad Google servers or what is the problem?

I appreciate any help.

Full code:

```
function analyse() {
  let firstTeamName = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Übersicht").getRange("AZ1:AZ1").getValue();
  console.info("MAIN: (1/9) Teams loaded");
  analyseTeam(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(firstTeamName));
  analyseTeam(spreadsheet.getSheetByName("TRUEs"));
  for (let id = 1; id < 8; ++id) if (id !== Number(firstTeamName.startsWith("Tag ") ? firstTeamName.substring(4) : 0)) analyseTeam(spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Tag " + id));
}

function response(url) {
  response(url, 1);
}

function response(url, id) {
  makeABreak.push(new Date().getTime());
  if (makeABreak.length === 100) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - makeABreak.shift()) < 120000) {
      console.warn("I make a break!");
      Utilities.sleep(120000);
      makeABreak = [];
    }
  }
  try {
    return JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText());
  } catch(exception) {
    console.error("Exception for (" + url + "):" + exception);
    return id === 2 ? null : response(url, 2);
  }
```

```
let sheet;
let puuids;
let newPlayers;
let section;
let sectionRow;
let sectionLine;
let lineRecentGames;
let normsInSection;

function analyseTeam(sheetToAnalyse) {
  // Initializing
  currentTime = new Date();
  sheet = sheetToAnalyse;
  puuids = [];
  newPlayers = [];
  normsInSection = [];
  section = -1;
  sectionRow = -1;
  sectionLine = -1;
  lineRecentGames = (sheet.getName() === "TRUEs" ? 22 : 17);

  // Load player Data & Custom Games
  let games = loadPlayers();
  console.info(sheet.getName() + ": Spieler geladen, Elos aktualisiert");
  games.sort();
  findPrimeLeague(games);
  console.info(sheet.getName() + ": PrimeLeague Spiele geladen.");

  // Load Normal Games
  findNorms();
  console.info("MAIN: " + sheet.getName() + " loaded");
}

function loadPlayers() {
  let recentCustomGames = [];
  let recentCustomGamesData = sheet.getRange(lineRecentGames + 2, 1, 250, 1).getValues();
  for (let customGameId in recentCustomGamesData) {
    if (recentCustomGamesData.hasOwnProperty(customGameId)) {
      recentCustomGames.push(recentCustomGamesData[customGameId][0]);
      if (recentCustomGamesData[customGameId][1] == "" || new Date().getTime() - new Date(recentCustomGamesData[customGameId][1]).getTime() > 15552000000) 
        sheet.getRange(lineRecentGames + 2 + customGameId, 1, 1, 73).setValues([["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
          "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]]);
    } 
  }
  let games = [];
  let column = 22;
  let names = [];

  let playerData = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getName() === "TRUEs" ? 20 : 15, 3).getValues();
  let puuid;
  let summonerData;
  let elo = "U";
  for (let playerId in playerData) {
    if (playerData.hasOwnProperty(playerId)) {
      puuid = playerData[playerId][1];
      // Insert new Players
      if (puuid.length < 10) {
        if (playerData[playerId][0] !== "") {
          let profileContent = response('https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/' + playerData[playerId][0] + apikey);
          puuid = profileContent.puuid;
          playerData[playerId][1] = profileContent.puuid;
          newPlayers.push(puuid);
        }
      } else {
        if (currentTime.getHours() === 23) {
          summonerData = response('https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-puuid/' + puuid + apikey);
          playerData[playerId][0] = summonerData.name;

          if (sheet.getName().startsWith("Tag")) column = Number(sheet.getName().substring(4));
          else if (sheet.getName() === "Scrim") column = 8;
          else {
            let scrimTeams = inputSheet.getRange(2, 12, 1, Number(inputSheet.getRange("C2:C2").getValue())).getValues()[0];
            for (let scrimTeam in scrimTeams) if (scrimTeams.hasOwnProperty(scrimTeam) && String(scrimTeams[scrimTeam]) === sheet.getName()) column = scrimTeam + 9;
          }
          //RANKED
          let rankedData = response('https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/league/v4/entries/by-summoner/' + summonerData.id + apikey);
          for (let entry in rankedData) {
            if (rankedData.hasOwnProperty(entry) && rankedData[entry].queueType === "RANKED_SOLO_5x5")
              elo = String(rankedData[entry].tier).substring(0, 1) + (rankedData[entry].rank === "I" ? "1" : rankedData[entry].rank === "II" ? "2" : rankedData[entry].rank === "III"?"3":"4");
          }
          playerData[playerId][2] = elo;
        }
      }
      puuids.push(puuid);

      if (puuid !== "" && playerId < 10) {
        let turnamentGames = response("https://europe.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/by-puuid/" + puuid + "/ids?type=tourney&start=0&count=100&startTime=" + (parseInt((currentTime / 1000) - 15552000)) + "&" + apikey.substring(1));
        for (let turnamentGame in turnamentGames) if (turnamentGames.hasOwnProperty(turnamentGame) && !games.includes(turnamentGames[turnamentGame]) && !recentCustomGames.includes(turnamentGames[turnamentGame])) games.push(turnamentGames[turnamentGame]);
        

        let clashGames = response("https://europe.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/by-puuid/" + puuid + "/ids?startTime=" + (parseInt((currentTime / 1000) - 15552000)) +
            "&queue=700&start=0&count=100&" + apikey.substring(1));
        for (let clashGame in clashGames) if (clashGames.hasOwnProperty(clashGame) && !games.includes(clashGames[clashGame]) && !recentCustomGames.includes(clashGames[clashGame]))
          games.push(clashGames[clashGame]);
      }
      names.push(new Array(playerData[playerId][0]));
      playerData[playerId].splice(0, 1);
    }
  }
  //determineAmountofTourneyGames(playerData);
  inputSheet.getRange(4, column + 3, playerData.length, 1).setValues(names);
  sheet.getRange(2, 2, playerData.length, 2).setValues(playerData);
  return games;
}

function findPrimeLeague(games) {
  const championData = response("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/" + response("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/api/versions.json")[0] + "/data/en_US/champion.json");
  let startAmount = Number(sheet.getRange("B" + lineRecentGames + ":B" + lineRecentGames).getValue());
  let amount = Number(startAmount);
  let gamesArrays = [];
  let ganks = sheet.getRange("P1:R1").getValues()[0]

  for (let game in games) {
    if (games.hasOwnProperty(game)) {
      let gameId = games[game];
      let gameData = response("https://europe.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/" + gameId + apikey);
      let durationSeconds = Number(gameData.info.gameDuration);
      if (durationSeconds > 36000) durationSeconds = Math.round(durationSeconds / 1000);

      //determineTeam
      let team;
      let win;
      let players = gameData.info.participants;
      for (let playerId in players) {
        if (players.hasOwnProperty(playerId)) {
          let participant = players[playerId];
          if (puuids.includes(participant.puuid)) {
            team = participant.teamId;
            win = participant.win;
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      let teams = gameData.info.teams;
      let banns = [];
      let banIds = team === 200 ? (teams[1].bans).concat(teams[0].bans) : (teams[0].bans).concat(teams[1].bans);
      if (championData !== undefined) {
        let champions = championData.data;
        for (let champion in champions) if (champions.hasOwnProperty(champion))
          for (let ban in banIds) if (banIds.hasOwnProperty(ban) && banIds[ban].championId === Number(champions[champion].key)) banns.push(champions[champion].id);
      }

      let top = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
      let jgl = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
      let mid = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
      let bot = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
      let sup = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
      let totalCS = 0;
      let supGold;
      for (let playerId in players) {
        if (players.hasOwnProperty(playerId)) {
          let participant = players[playerId];
          if (puuids.includes(participant.puuid)) totalCS += (parseInt(participant.neutralMinionsKilled) + parseInt(participant.totalMinionsKilled));
          if (participant.teamPosition === "TOP") top = determinePlayer(participant, top);
          if (participant.teamPosition === "JUNGLE") jgl = determinePlayer(participant, jgl);
          if (participant.teamPosition === "MIDDLE") mid = determinePlayer(participant, mid);
          if (participant.teamPosition === "BOTTOM") bot = determinePlayer(participant, bot);
          if (participant.teamPosition === "UTILITY") sup = determinePlayer(participant, sup);
          if (puuids.includes(participant.puuid) && participant.teamPosition === "UTILITY") supGold = participant.goldEarned;
        }
      }

      let gameDetails = response("https://europe.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/" + gameId + "/timeline" + apikey);
      let detailedParticipants = gameDetails.metadata.participants;
      let topId = -1;
      let jglId = -1;
      let midId = -1;
      let botId = -1;
      let supId = -1;
      for (let participant in detailedParticipants) {
        if (detailedParticipants.hasOwnProperty(participant)) {
          if (detailedParticipants[participant] === top[0]) topId = Number(participant) + 1;
          else if (detailedParticipants[participant] === jgl[0]) jglId = Number(participant) + 1;
          else if (detailedParticipants[participant] === mid[0]) midId = Number(participant) + 1;
          else if (detailedParticipants[participant] === bot[0]) botId = Number(participant) + 1;
          else if (detailedParticipants[participant] === sup[0]) supId = Number(participant) + 1;
        }
      }

      let topSoloKills = 0;
      let jglSuccessGanks = 0;
      let jglTriedGanks = 0;
      let midSoloKills = 0;
      let botMinions = 0;
      let supSuccessGanks = 0;
      let recentDamageStats = 0;
      let totalDamage = 0;
      for (let frameId in gameDetails.info.frames) {
        let events = gameDetails.info.frames[frameId].events;
        for (let eventObj in events) {
          if (events.hasOwnProperty(eventObj)) {
            let event = events[eventObj];
            let assistingIds = event.assistingParticipantIds;
            if (event.type === "CHAMPION_KILL" && assistingIds === undefined && topId > 0 && event.killerId === topId) topSoloKills++;
            if (event.type === "CHAMPION_KILL" && assistingIds === undefined && midId > 0 && event.killerId === midId) midSoloKills++;
            if (event.type === "CHAMPION_KILL" && event.timestamp < 1000000) {
              if (jglId > 0 && event.killerId === jglId) {
                if ((event.position.x - event.position.y) < -3000) {
                  ++ganks[0];
                } else if ((event.position.x - event.position.y) > 3000) {
                  ++ganks[2];
                } else {
                  ++ganks[1];
                }
                jglSuccessGanks++;
              } 
              for (let ids in assistingIds) 
                if (assistingIds.hasOwnProperty(ids) && jglId > 0 && assistingIds !== undefined && assistingIds[ids] === jglId) {
                  if ((event.position.x - event.position.y) < -3000) {
                    ++ganks[0];
                  } else if ((event.position.x - event.position.y) > 3000) {
                    ++ganks[2];
                  } else {
                    ++ganks[1];
                  }
                  jglSuccessGanks++;
                } 
              for (let ids in assistingIds) if (assistingIds.hasOwnProperty(ids) && supId > 0 && assistingIds !== undefined && assistingIds[ids] === supId &&
                  (event.killerId === midId || event.killerId === topId)) supSuccessGanks++;
            }
            if (event.type === "CHAMPION_KILL" && event.victimId === jglId && event.timestamp < 1000000) {
              if ((event.position.x - event.position.y) < -3000) {
                ++ganks[0];
              } else if ((event.position.x - event.position.y) > 3000) {
                ++ganks[2];
              } else {
                ++ganks[1];
              }
            }
          }
        }
        let frame = gameDetails.info.frames[frameId];
        if (jglId > 0 && frameId < 16) {
          totalDamage = frame.participantFrames[jglId].damageStats.totalDamageDoneToChampions;
          if (recentDamageStats !== totalDamage) jglTriedGanks++;
        }
        if (frameId == 15 && botId > 0) botMinions = frame.participantFrames[botId].minionsKilled + frame.participantFrames[botId].jungleMinionsKilled;
        recentDamageStats = totalDamage;
      }

      top[9] = (topId === -1) ? "" : topSoloKills;
      jgl[9] = (jglId === -1) ? "" : jglSuccessGanks / jglTriedGanks;
      mid[9] = (midId === -1) ? "" : midSoloKills;
      bot[9] = (botId === -1) ? "" : botMinions;
      sup[9] = (supId === -1) ? "" : supSuccessGanks;

      let date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(Number(gameData.info.gameCreation)), CalendarApp.getTimeZone(), 'dd.MM.YYYY HH:mm');
      let type = gameData.info.gameType === "MATCHED_GAME" ? "C" : "L";
      let totalGold = parseInt(top[6] === "" ? 0 : top[6]) + parseInt(jgl[6] === "" ? 0 : jgl[6]) + parseInt(mid[6] === "" ?
          0 : mid[6]) + parseInt(bot[6] === "" ? 0 : bot[6]) + parseInt(supGold === "" ? 0 : supGold);
      let objectives = (team === 100) ? gameData.info.teams[0].objectives : gameData.info.teams[1].objectives;
      let tower = (team === 100 ? objectives.tower.kills : objectives.tower.kills);
      let drakes = (team === 100 ? objectives.dragon.kills : objectives.dragon.kills);
      let inhibs = (team === 100 ? objectives.inhibitor.kills : objectives.inhibitor.kills);
      let heralds = (team === 100 ? objectives.riftHerald.kills : objectives.riftHerald.kills);
      let barons = (team === 100 ? objectives.baron.kills : objectives.baron.kills);
      let gameArray = [gameId, date, durationSeconds, type, win, banns[0], banns[1], banns[2], banns[3], banns[4], banns[5], banns[6], banns[7], banns[8], banns[9], top[0], top[1], top[2],
        top[3], top[4], top[5], top[6], top[7], top[8], jgl[0], jgl[1], jgl[2], jgl[3], jgl[4], jgl[5], jgl[6], jgl[7], jgl[8], mid[0], mid[1], mid[2], mid[3], mid[4], mid[5], mid[6], mid[7],
        mid[8], bot[0], bot[1], bot[2], bot[3], bot[4], bot[5], bot[6], bot[7], bot[8], sup[0], sup[1], sup[2], sup[3], sup[4], sup[5], sup[6], sup[7], sup[8], totalCS, totalGold,
        tower, drakes, inhibs, heralds, barons, top[9], jgl[9], mid[9], bot[9], sup[9]];
      if (sheet.getName() === "TRUEs") gameArray.splice(60, 0, supGold); else gameArray.push("");
      gamesArrays.push(gameArray);
      ++amount;
    }
  }

  if (gamesArrays.length > 0) {
    if (startAmount % 250 < amount % 250) sheet.getRange(lineRecentGames + 2 + (startAmount % 250), 1, gamesArrays.length, gamesArrays[0].length).setValues(gamesArrays);
    else {
      let remainingSpace = 250 - (startAmount % 250);
      let lastArray = gamesArrays.slice(remainingSpace);
      sheet.getRange(lineRecentGames + 2 + (startAmount % 250), 1, remainingSpace, gamesArrays[0].length).setValues(gamesArrays.slice(0, remainingSpace));
      sheet.getRange(lineRecentGames + 2, 1, lastArray.length, gamesArrays[0].length).setValues(lastArray);
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange("B" + lineRecentGames + ":B" + lineRecentGames).setValue(amount);
  sheet.getRange("P1:R1").setValues([ganks]);
}

// TODO CALC!A1
function findNorms() {
  let allgames = [];
  let time = Number(sheet.getRange("K1:K1").getValue());
  if (time === 0) sheet.getRange("L1:L1").setValue("init");
  let recentNumber = Number(sheet.getRange("B1:B1").getValue());
  let amount = Number(sheet.getRange("CM1:CM1").getValue());
  let init = String(sheet.getRange("L1:L1").getValue()) === "init";
  if (init) {
    if (amount > 0) {
      let initAddNorms = sheet.getRange(3, 91, amount, 1).getValues();
      for (let normId in initAddNorms) {
        let norm = initAddNorms[normId][0];
        if (initAddNorms.hasOwnProperty(normId) && !allgames.includes(norm)) {
          allgames.push(norm);
        }
      }
    } else allgames = addPlayersGames(puuids, allgames);

    console.log(allgames.length);
  } else {
    if (time < parseInt((currentTime / 1000) - 15552000)) time = parseInt((currentTime / 1000) - 15552000)
    for (let puuid in puuids) {
      if (puuids.hasOwnProperty(puuid) && puuids[puuid] !== "" && puuids[puuid] !== undefined) {
        let games40 = response("https://europe.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/by-puuid/" + puuids[puuid] + "/ids?startTime=" +time+"&queue=400&start=0&count=100&"+apikey.substring(1));
        for (let game in games40) if(games40.hasOwnProperty(game) && !allgames.includes(games40[game]) && Number(String(games40[game]).substring(5))>recentNumber) allgames.push(games40[game]);
        let games42 = response("https://europe.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/by-puuid/" + puuids[puuid] + "/ids?startTime=" +time+"&queue=420&start=0&count=100&"+apikey.substring(1));
        for (let game in games42) if(games42.hasOwnProperty(game) && !allgames.includes(games42[game]) && Number(String(games42[game]).substring(5))>recentNumber) allgames.push(games42[game]);
        let games44 = response("https://europe.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/by-puuid/" + puuids[puuid] + "/ids?startTime=" +time+"&queue=440&start=0&count=100&"+apikey.substring(1));
        for (let game in games44) if(games44.hasOwnProperty(game) && !allgames.includes(games44[game]) && Number(String(games44[game]).substring(5))>recentNumber) allgames.push(games44[game]);
      }
    }
  }

  for (let game in allgames) if (Number(allgames[game].substring(5)) < recentNumber) allgames.splice(game, 1);
  if (newPlayers.length > 0 && !init) allgames = addPlayersGames(newPlayers, allgames);
  allgames.sort();
  console.info(sheet.getName() + ": " + ((allgames.length === 0) ? "No more matches " : allgames.length + " new matches"));
  if (allgames.length > 0) {
    let initNormsArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < allgames.length; ++i) initNormsArray.push("");
    
    if (init && allgames.length > 0) {
      for (let normId in allgames) if (allgames.hasOwnProperty(normId)) initNormsArray[normId] = [allgames[normId]];
      sheet.getRange(3, 91, initNormsArray.length, 1).setValues(initNormsArray);
    }
    for (let game in allgames) {
      let gameContent = response("https://europe.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/" + allgames[game] + apikey);
      if (response !== undefined && gameContent !== undefined) performGame(gameContent, gameContent.info.participants);
      else console.error(allgames[game] + " skipped");
    }
    if (normsInSection.length > 0) sheet.getRange(sectionLine, sectionRow, normsInSection.length, 16).setValues(normsInSection);
    sheet.getRange("K1:K1").setValue(parseInt(Number(currentTime.getTime()) / 1000));
    if (init) {
      for (let normId in allgames) if (allgames.hasOwnProperty(normId)) initNormsArray[normId] = [allgames[normId]];
      sheet.getRange(3, 91, initNormsArray.length, 1).setValues(initNormsArray);
      console.log("OUT");
    }
  }

  if (init) sheet.getRange("L1:L1").setValue("");
}

function performGame(game, players) {
  let timestamp = Number(game.info.gameCreation);
  let sectionNew = (parseInt((new Date(timestamp).getTime() - new Date('June 16, 2021 00:00:00 +0000').getTime()) / 864000000)) % 20 + 1;
  if (sectionNew !== section) {
    if (normsInSection.length > 0) sheet.getRange(sectionLine, sectionRow, normsInSection.length, 16).setValues(normsInSection);
    normsInSection = [];
    section = sectionNew;
    let sectionRowBig = (section === 1) ? (section + 3) : (section + 4);
    sectionRow = (sectionRowBig % 5 === 4) ? 74 : (sectionRowBig % 5 * 17 + 1);
    sectionLine = sheet.getRange("BL" + (300 + section) + ":BL" + (300 + section)).getValue() + (parseInt(sectionRowBig / 5) * 500) + 1;
  }

  let duration = game.info.gameDuration;
  let matchId = game.metadata.matchId;
  let date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(timestamp), CalendarApp.getTimeZone(), 'dd.MM.YYYY HH:mm');
  for (let playerId in players) {
    if (players.hasOwnProperty(playerId)) {
      let participant = players[playerId];
      if (puuids.includes(participant.puuid)) {
        let lane = participant.teamPosition;
        let puuid = participant.puuid;
        let champion = participant.championName;
        let enemy = "";
        let win = participant.win;
        let cs = (participant.neutralMinionsKilled + participant.totalMinionsKilled) * 60 / ((duration > 10000) ? (duration / 1000) : duration);
        cs = Math.round(cs * 10) / 10;
        let gold = participant.goldEarned;
        let egold = 0;
        for (let enemyPlayer in players) {
          if (players.hasOwnProperty(enemyPlayer)) {
            let counterpart = players[enemyPlayer];
            if (counterpart.teamPosition === lane && counterpart.puuid !== puuid) {
              enemy = counterpart.championName;
              egold = counterpart.goldEarned;
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        let gdiff = (egold > 0) ? gold - egold : 0;
        let gpm = parseInt(gold * 60 / ((duration > 10000) ? (duration / 1000) : duration));
        let ad = participant.physicalDamageDealtToChampions;
        let ap = participant.magicDamageDealtToChampions;
        let td = participant.trueDamageDealtToChampions;
        let taken = participant.totalDamageTaken;
        let healed = participant.totalHeal;
        let cc = participant.timeCCingOthers;
        normsInSection.push([matchId, date, lane, puuid, champion, enemy, win, cs, gdiff, gpm, ad, ap, td, taken, healed, cc]);
      }
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange("B1:B1").setValue(matchId.substring(5));
}

function fetchResponses(puuid, epoch) {
  let matchIds = [];
  let contentEpoch = fetchresponse(puuid, epoch, "400");
  for (let matchId in contentEpoch) if (contentEpoch.hasOwnProperty(matchId) && !matchIds.includes(contentEpoch[matchId])) matchIds.push(contentEpoch[matchId]);
  contentEpoch = fetchresponse(puuid, epoch, "420");
  for (let matchId in contentEpoch) if (contentEpoch.hasOwnProperty(matchId) && !matchIds.includes(contentEpoch[matchId])) matchIds.push(contentEpoch[matchId]);
  contentEpoch = fetchresponse(puuid, epoch, "440");
  for (let matchId in contentEpoch) if (contentEpoch.hasOwnProperty(matchId) && !matchIds.includes(contentEpoch[matchId])) matchIds.push(contentEpoch[matchId]);
  return matchIds;
}

function fetchresponse(puuid, epoch, queueId) {
  return response("https://europe.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/by-puuid/" + puuid + "/ids?startTime=" + (parseInt(currentTime / 1000) - (3000000 * epoch)) + "&endTime=" +
      (parseInt(currentTime / 1000) - (3000000 * (epoch - 1))) + "&queue=" + queueId + "&start=0&count=100&" + apikey.substring(1));
}

function determinePlayer(participant, array) {
  return puuids.includes(participant.puuid) ? [participant.puuid, participant.championName, array[2], participant.kills, participant.deaths, participant.assists, (participant.teamPosition ===
      "UTILITY") ? participant.visionScore : participant.goldEarned, (participant.teamPosition === "UTILITY") ? participant.visionWardsBoughtInGame : participant.totalDamageDealtToChampions,
    array[8], array[9]] : [array[0], array[1], participant.championName, array[3], array[4], array[5], array[6], array[7], participant.goldEarned, array[9]];
}

function addPlayersGames(puuids, allgames) {
  console.log("Load " + puuids);
  for (let puuid in puuids) {
    if (puuids.hasOwnProperty(puuid)) {
      for (let epochId = 1; epochId < 11; ++epochId) {
        let contentEpoch = fetchResponses(puuids[puuid], epochId);
        for (let matchId in contentEpoch) if (!allgames.includes(contentEpoch[matchId])) allgames.push(contentEpoch[matchId]);
      }
    }
  }
  return allgames;
}

function determineAmountofTourneyGames(playerData) {
  let alltourneygamesAmountArray = [];
  for (let playerId in playerData) {
    if (playerData.hasOwnProperty(playerId)) {
      let puuid = playerData[playerId][1];
      alltourneygamesAmountArray.push((puuid.length > 10) ? ([response("https://europe.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/by-puuid/" + puuid + "/ids?type=tourney&start=0&count=100&" + apikey.substring(1)).length]) : ([0]));
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(2, 21, playerData.length, 1).setValues(alltourneygamesAmountArray);
}
```

Comment: Please provide the entire code. Based on this it is difficult to asses the issue. Please also provide the function `analyse()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the error is that you are calling `sheet` too many times, and each call is a request which takes time to process and ultimately leads to the timeout. The easy sounding solution is reduce the calls of `sheet.getRange()` and `sheet.setValue()` and `sheet.getName()` etc… so that you ideally do them once per each sheet you are working on. A simple example would be as follows, where everything is done once (except the api call, which ideally should also be done using a bulk api).

```
function writePlayersApiResToSheet( sheet ){
  // get all players data from the sheet in only 1 call
  const allPlayers = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()

  // remove the header in row 1
  allPlayers.shift()

  // api responses will be pushed here
  const output = []

  // do something, like call the api for each user
  allPlayers.forEach( player=> output.push([getPlayerInfoFromApi(player)]) )

  // write to the sheet once
  const startRow = 2
  const startCol = 10 // or wherever the api res should go
  sheet.getRange( startRow, startCol, allPlayers.length, 1).setValues( output )
}
```

Google provides this [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#exception_messages) on this topics.

Comment: Thank you i will try that one out.

Comment: Thanks again. The execution now is 10 times faster. Really!

Comment: Gerne :) Please mark the answer with the check mark in order to confirm your question is resolved.